# How to make an .R/Makevars file that works on two systems?

Tags: r, makefile

I use the same user directory on two different operating systems. Can I specify a conditional set of Makevars rules depending on the operating system? One of my operating systems is older and can't support all the features of the other. If so, could you provide an example?

I would imagine it would be like:

```
os = $(uname -a | awk '{print $2}')
ifeq(os, "redhat7")
    CC=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc
    CXX=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/g++
    ...
endif
```

but I'm not sure how to make the variable os.

Answer (score 1):

As no one else seems to care, I dare to propose [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt), a GNUmake helper library. It was designed with such use cases in mind. You can define tables with your option flags and `select` them by a column (or combination thereof) very similar to a modest form of an SQL select:

```
include gmtt-master/gmtt-master/gmtt.mk

# Table with two (indicator "2" as first element) columns. First column is a glob which matches the OS, second is option string
# Warning! No spaces in either column are allowed - use $(call spc-mask,...options...) if there are.
define CC_OPTIONS_TBL
2
redhat[!7]* /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/gcc
redhat7     /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc
suse*       /opt/bin/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc
endef

CC_OPT := $(call select,2,$(CC_OPTIONS_TBL),$$(call glob-match,$(MY_OS),$$1))

$(info CC_OPT = $(CC_OPT))

define CXX_OPTIONS_TBL
2
redhat[!7]* $(call spc-mask, /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/gcc -DREDHAT -O2)
redhat7     $(call spc-mask, /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -DREDHAT_7 -O3)
suse*       $(call spc-mask, /opt/bin/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -DSUSE -O0)
suse8       $(call spc-mask, -DFOO -DBAR)
endef

CXX_OPT := $(call spc-unmask,$(call select,2,$(CXX_OPTIONS_TBL),$$(call glob-match,$(MY_OS),$$1)))

$(info CXX_OPT = $(CXX_OPT))
```

Output:

```
mark@zws103 ~
$ make MY_OS=suse
CC_OPT =  /opt/bin/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc
CXX_OPT =   /opt/bin/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -DSUSE -O0
make: *** Keine Ziele.  Schluss.

mark@zws103 ~
$ make MY_OS=redhat6.1
CC_OPT =  /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/gcc
CXX_OPT =   /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/gcc -DREDHAT -O2
make: *** Keine Ziele.  Schluss.

mark@zws103 ~
$ make MY_OS=redhat7
CC_OPT =  /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc
CXX_OPT =   /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -DREDHAT_7 -O3
make: *** Keine Ziele.  Schluss.

mark@zws103 ~
$ make MY_OS=redhat7.1
CC_OPT =
CXX_OPT =
make: *** Keine Ziele.  Schluss.
```

Note that the last OS string "redhat7.1" didn't match any of the globs in the table.

Also note that the `select` return *all* lines that match:

```
$ make MY_OS=suse8
CC_OPT =  /opt/bin/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc
CXX_OPT =   /opt/bin/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -DSUSE -O0  -DFOO -DBAR
make: *** Keine Ziele.  Schluss.
```

Comment: If I understand this right, this approach involves generating a new makefile every session, overwriting the old one each time. There is no way to embed this into a single makefile?

Comment: Um, no, there is no need to generate a makefile. Just copy the snippet into your `makefile`. The one thing that you need is to have `gmtt.mk` on your disk. Maybe you are confused about the output - I just inserted `$(info)` to show the relevant variables. `$(info)` is the equivalent to C's `printf()` and is mainly used for debugging makefiles.